# Friend functions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, class, oop, output, friend-function

I'm working in *Matlab* using *OOP* phenomena, However I want a phenomena of *friend function* like in `C/C++` i.e to pass one function's output to other in the same class just for its use.
Here, `myClass` is my class, in which, an output of `myFunc1` is required by `myFunc2`, How can I make these two functions a friend. Is there any facility like other languages?

**My Code:**

```
classdef myClass
    properties (Access=private)
        M;
      T
    end
    methods
        function obj = myClass(M,T)
            obj.M= M;
            obj.T=T;

        end
        function H=myFunc1(obj)
            obj.M{obj.jj}=jj+ii;
           H=obj.M{obj.jj};
        end

        function myFunc2(obj)
            obj.T= H;
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of one `class-member` function to other is simple call that function and collect output in that function, the code:

```
function myFunc2(obj)
      H=myFunc1(obj);
      obj.T= H;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want, but I guess that you want to execute `myFunc1` inside `myFunc2`? If this is the case you can simply execute `myFunc1` inside `myFunc2` as follows: `obj.myFunc1();`. For example (this is general example):

```
classdef myClass
    properties (Access=private)
        M;
        T;
    end
    methods
        function obj = myClass()
        end
        function H=myFunc1(obj)
            H = 3;
        end

        function myFunc2(obj)
            disp(obj.myFunc1())
        end
    end
end
```

if you want to make `myFunc2` hidden from the rest of the class, you can define it as a nested function, e.g.:

```
classdef myClass
    properties (Access=private)
        M;
        T;
    end
    methods
        function obj = myClass()
        end

        function myFunc2(obj)

            function H=myFunc1()
                H = 3;
            end

            disp(myFunc1())
        end
    end
end
```